# (Spring) th:with based on a condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to assign a variable in thymeleaf based on a condtion:

```
<span th:with="valueID=${${myField != null} ? {myField.value.getId()}}">
```

This does not work, and gives me an exception:

```
"Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: `"${myField == null} ? {myField.value.getId()}"`"
```

What am I doing wrong?

In fact I want to set `valueID` to `{myField.value.getId()}` when myField is not `null`.

Comment: This works for me - not Spring dialect, just standard Thymeleaf dialect (Spring may have another way to do this): `<span th:with="valueID=${myField != null} ? ${myField.value.id} ">`. It assumes you have the relevant getters for `value` and `id`. What do you want to happen when `myField` is null? You can use the full `? :` operator, also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `?` operator should be enough:

```
<span th:with="valueID=${myField?.value.getId()}">
```

The getter method can be omitted to:

```
<span th:with="valueID=${myField?.value.id}">
```

However, the code is still not null-safe since `value` can be `null` as well.

Comment: Looks interestings, but I get:

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "myField?.value.getId()" (template: "base.entity.generic/GenericTableWithIdListing" - line 122, col 31)

...
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getId() on null context object

...
I'll have to check this another day I think, thank you until now :)

Comment: As I told you, `value` might be null which probably caused this. You might want: `<span th:with="valueID=${myField?.value?.id}">`